# Wordpress appends RSS item with unwanted content

Tags: rss, feed, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

Wordpress is adding a message to the end of each item in RSS feed that reads

"The post [post_name] appeared first on ]site_name]."

I want this message to go away. I browsed through a my feed.php files, but couldn't find the code that assembles this message. Where should I look for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text is probably being added to your feed by the "WordPress SEO by Yoast" plugin.  In your admin panel menu, go to SEO, RSS.  Delete everything in the box labeled "Content to put after each post."

Comment: That's exactly what it was.  Props to Ben Miller.

Answer (score 0):

This text is probably being added by the Yoast SEO plugin. To remove it:

1. Navigate to **SEO** > **Advanced** > **RSS**.
2. Remove the text in **Content to put after each post in the feed**:
3. Click **Save changes**.